# dictionary key error python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I get the error "Key Error: 'tempMax'".

Can anyone tell what the problem is with the following code:

```
def catagorise(self, day, cat, f):
    self.features.setdefault(cat, {f:{'high':0,'mid':0,'low':0}})

    if f == 'tempMean':
        if day.tempMean > 15.0:
            self.features[cat][f]['high'] += 1
        elif day.tempMean > 8.0 and day.tempMean < 15.0:
            self.features[cat][f]['mid'] += 1
        elif day.tempMean <= 8.0:
            self.features[cat][f]['low'] += 1       

    if f == 'tempMax':
        if day.tempMax > 15.0:
            self.features[cat][f]['high'] += 1
        elif day.tempMax > 8.0 and day.tempMax < 15.0:
            self.features[cat][f]['mid'] += 1
        elif day.tempMax <= 8.0:
            self.features[cat][f]['low'] += 1
```

A day is an object which has variables such as mean temperature, max temperature etc. Cat is the category which it will be put into e.g 'Fog', 'Rain', 'Snow', 'None' and f is the feature to check e.g. 'tempMax'

The features dictionary is defined when the class is created.

Comment: and the rest of the traceback?

Comment: @MattH The rest of the traceback would spoil the *riddle*

Answer (score 4):

The issue is in the setdefault call.
f is set to tempMax but tempMax was never initialized.
In this case it needs to be initialized as a dictionary because you have 'high' as a key

```
self.features[cat][f]['high']


self.features[cat]['tempMax'] = {}
```

If you come from a php background then this is a common mistake.  In python you have to initialize your dictionaries.  They have to be initialized at every nested level.
Common way to do it is...

```
try:
   self.features[cat]
except KeyError, e:
   self.features[cat] = {}

try
   self.features[cat]['tempHigh']
except KeyError, e:
   self.features[cat]['tempHigh'] = {}
```

Answer (score 1):

`dict.setdefault()` only sets the key *once*. If you pass `'tempMean'` once then you will not get a chance to set `tempMax`.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your method

```
self.features.setdefault(cat,{f:{'high':0,'mid':0,'low':0}})
```

sets `self.features[cat]` to the given value only if it is not already set, and does nothing otherwise.  In the latter case, it might happen (and obviously happens) that the dictionary `self.features[cat]` does not have the key `f`, so trying to access `self.features[cat][f]` will raise a `KeyError`.